# Stop text overflow on user submitted forms

Tags: forms, text, overflow

http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=16&id=16

As you can see here I am having a text overflow issues. What can I do to stop it from overflowing? How would I stop the text at the max width of the container and have it wrap to the next line when the user submits the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

To `div#postcenter > div`, so you end up with this:

```
div#postcenter > div {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

`word-wrap: break-word` always ensures that long, non-breaking words wrap at the end of the line (at least in browsers that support it).